# How to make a list with all messages send it by Parse Push Notification Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I build an app in Android using Xamarin!

Here is my Channel call by "RE"

[image: Parse Console]

Here is my Message
[image: Parse Console]

Everything Works fine, but what i really want is, create a list in my Android app with all those messages who i send it through this channel "RE"

if i have 10 Messages i want to list all and storage!

Here is my code in Android Xamarin to create a channel!

```
private async void Channel()
    {
        var installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
        installation.Channels = new List<string> { "RE" };
        await installation.SaveAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry if this comment is not relevant but to just get all the objects from a class in parse isn't this enough: var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Name");
   results = await query.FindAsync();
objects = results.ToList();
Except if im not understand correctly of what you want

Comment: hi @CDrosos lets say i have two differents channels ok ? and i want to list all messages i send it by this channel, when you say 
`ParseObject.GetQuery("Name"); ` that name is the channel that i subscribed?

Comment: If the problem is that you want to change the authenticated parse channel then parse inform that this should defined on the Application class on the beggining on the Application, i think it cannot be changed but maybe im wrong

Comment: @CDrosos i found this tutorial but is in Native Android [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/) and he make a list with all messages, but i dont know how to do in Xamarin.

Comment: Sorry im not good on converting Java to C# either